# How to implement box selection in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, selection

I am trying to implement a selection box in Qt:[image: Selection]

When the user holds down LMB and drags, a rectangle is created and drawn real time to the screen. I also want to be able to select on only one dimension.

I think overriding the methods `QWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent*), QWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent*)` may help, but I don't know how to dynamically obtain and draw the rect.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html